# login failed for user nt/authority

Tags: asp.net, sql, wcf

I am trying to deploy my website and wcf runs in my localhost...if i login i.e use db i am gettin this error...Any idea wht the pblm would be ?

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Comment: What does the connection string you're using look like?

Answer (score 2):

Few months ago I had also faced the same kind of problem. This occurred because by default the database connection string uses a trusted connection and When a client is accessing SQL Server via a trusted connection the database you are accessing might have a trusted connection account within the userlist with db_owner rights to the target database.Here are the steps to remove the error.
Here is the SOLUTION for the problem:

Its very simple, just you need to add a new user instead of the previous user for your database.

For example: I had a database named CRM having user crm. I created a new user for my database CRM as kos.
Here are the steps to do so:

1. Open your SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Click on the database node and then the Security node->Logins.

For further visit: http://kopila.com.np/login-failed-for-user-in-asp-net.html

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you're using Windows Authentication when the account that the ASP net process is running under doesn't have access to the sql server.